# How to disply URL as image & resized in another Excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

[Cell J Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tclA.png)

[image]

I'm looking to convert a URL into an image but I want the image in a new cell and sized to an inch by an inch.

I was able to get a script from another question asked, but need the extra script to add to it

This coding is the same from another question but not the additions of placing the image into a different cell and sizing it

so URL in column J puts image in column K sized to 1" x 1"

in this example, .insert (v) is inserted in cell "J"

```
Sub InstallPictures()

    Dim i As Long, v As String
    For i = 2 To 1903
        v = Cells(i, "J").Value
        If v = "" Then Exit Sub
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures
            .Insert (v)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: I am looking to have the URL in column J grab the image and paste it in another cell K with the size of 1" x 1".  The original image size if 4"x4".  The original question I posted only inserts the image in the same cell.  I want the URL to stay in J.